# Datediff function returning Null sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, date, datetime

> Note: it's hard to explain such a complicated situation especially when your native lang is not english. Sorry if it is hard to understand!

Here is my code:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[Date]
AS
  BEGIN
      SELECT ( dbo.Formula([Work], [Total]) ) AS [Finish],
             Datediff(day, [Finish], [Start]) AS [Days Planned]
      FROM   [Table1]
  END
```

I have an actual `[Finish]` column which is `Null` on `[Table1]`.
So `DATEDIFF(day,[Finish],[Start])` function giving `Null` values as expected.
I have created a `[Finish]` column on this stored procedure as you can see.

`dbo.Formula` is a function which is giving date type outcome.

`[Start]` is date type column filled with date type datas.
I know I can use `DATEDIFF(day,(dbo.Formula([Work],[Total])),[Start])` to calculate datediff, but it is not very handy for me to use it like that because of some reasons.

I also have `[Finish]` column on `[Table1]`.

**Is there any way to print the datas from `(dbo.Formula([Work],[Total]))` to my `[Finish]` column? And then Use it in datediff function?**

Comment: Is it Computed Columns you're after?

Comment: dbo.Formula is not stable function. it is changing itself via vb.net. So computed columns could not help.

Comment: I want to apply dbo.Formula() to my [Finish] column. And then use it to calculate [Days Planned] column. And them([Finish],[Days Planned]) show them bot on my Datagridview

Comment: Then I think you should run a job which periodically (based on requirements) updates DateFinish in your table; or you have to live with the double calculations if it can only be calculated at query time.

Comment: I did some research and found Inline table valued function which is returning table instead of data alone. I guess it will be my solution.

Comment: From MSDN [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) syntax is `DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )`. So `select datediff(day, '20160101', '20160201' ) = 31` but `select datediff(day, '20160201', '20160101' ) = -31`. I'm telling this for the line `Datediff(day, [Finish], [Start])`.

Comment: Datediff(day, [Start], [Finish])  I was allready using this syntax but I write it down wrongly. Thanks anyways. I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[Date]
AS
  begin
      declare @var date
      Select @var= dbo.NewFinishDate([Work], [Total])  from [Table1]
      SELECT @var AS [Finish],Datediff(day, [Start], @var ) AS [Days Planned]
      FROM   [Table1]
  END
```

I have added a paremeter for my function. It worked well.